# Force Jetty to make 301 redirect

Tags: http, redirect, seo, jetty

I have Jetty application which is very big.
I need to replace all 302 redirects to 301.

Can I force Jetty to always do 301 redirect when doing response.sendRedirect('someURL') ?

Comment: hi, did you figure this out by any chance?

thanks

Comment: I did not find solution. Jetty 6.1.10

Answer (score 1):

Hacks for jetty 6 and 8:

```
if (server.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion().startsWith("8")) {
  try {
    // Force 302 redirect status code into 301 'permanent redirect'
    Field statusField = HttpGenerator.class.getDeclaredField("__status");
    statusField.setAccessible(true);
    Object[] statusMap = (Object[]) statusField.get(HttpStatus.class);
    statusMap[HttpStatus.MOVED_TEMPORARILY_302] = statusMap[HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY_301];
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
} else if (server.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion().startsWith("6")) {
  try {
    // Force 302 redirect status code into 301 'permanent redirect'
    Field statusField = HttpStatus.class
        .getDeclaredField("__responseLine");
    statusField.setAccessible(true);
    Buffer[] responseLine = (Buffer[]) statusField
        .get(HttpStatus.class);
    byte[] bytes = responseLine[302].toString().replace("302", "301")
        .getBytes();
    responseLine[302] = new ByteArrayBuffer(bytes, 0, bytes.length,
        Buffer.IMMUTABLE);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
} else {
  throw new IllegalStateException("Jetty version "
      + server.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion()
      + " not yet supported?");
}
```